# Postfix Log: non-SMTP command from unknown IP address, "GET /aaa9 HTTP/1.1"

Tags: http, get, smtp, postfix-mta, hardening

I was troubleshooting some configurations on my mail server (postfix + dovecot) and while reviewing /var/log/syslog for postfix, I found that around 3am, postfix received a connection from an unknown IP and was issued a non-SMTP command, "GET /aaa9 HTTP/1.1".

My best guess is something is trying all ports for a web server and issuing an invalid command to have the server return an error code (and a server signature).

Any ideas? Is my mail server at any risk because of probing requests like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to worry about.
If you keep getting HTTP requests on and SMTP port from the same ip, you can block them using iptables or your company firewall.

Comment: Thank you. I did end up blocking it in my Ubuntu firewall.

Comment: Good. I think you can also setup fail2ban to scan logs and block ip according to predefined criteria.